# ExecutorService thread interval gap for script-engine

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, scriptengine

Here is the java method to encrypt the entry from a zip file and store it as file. There's no problem with the file reading and writing, so there's nothing to do with line 2-5. the issue is as described below...

`ExecutorService` object (es) used to get Zip Entry from `ZipEntry[]` array (ze) 1by1 and executed them concurrently by a fixed number of threads. Each thread is implemented with a `ScriptEngine` object from ScriptEngine array (se). When a thread finishing its execution, the script engine will be free for another entry. the problem is for the first batch of thread resource (entry), the executor do not evenly divide the entries. So there are more than an entry sent to a single engine which causing deadlock

1. how to delay the thread run a couple of millisecs after the previous one?

   OR
2. how to queue the resource when the script engine is busy. but i cant see a solution for this:

Here's the code:

```
static void encryptzip(ScriptEngine[] sc, String u, String k, ExecutorService es) throws... {
    ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(u);
    ZipEntry[] ze = getEntries(zf);
    byte[][] zb = getArrayOfEntryBytes(zf, ze);
    String p = getExtractionPath(u);
    for(int i=0;i<ze.length;i++){
        encentry ee = new encentry();
        ee.bytes = zb[i];
        ee.entry = ze[i];
        ee.key = k;
        ee.path = p;
        ee.script = getFreeScriptEngine(sc);
        es.execute(ee);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for `getFreeScriptEngine()`.

Comment: im sorry. it's secret. u can try it urself

Comment: How does getFreeScriptEngine() know the script engine is free? Does getting a script engine atomically mark that script engine as 'in use'?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is that `getFreeScriptEngine()`  is doing it is important to answer this.

If I undrestand correctly, you need to execute the encryption algorhitm sequentially to the free script engines. 
This is your main source of parallelism.
So you need to schedule the encryption tasks in blocking queues, which block on the same lock (or monitor, as in java monitor pattern) as the lock which you need to hold in order to correctly determine "free engine" in concurrent, multithreaded, runtime(very simply put the monitor on "isEngineFree" boolean variable, which perhaps an "engine" instance holds?).
Once you have determined the correct lock, you can have a `singleThreadedExecutor` executing tasks sequentially to the "free" engines. This you can achieve by handing out the "free engine"-blocked queues, which will hold the encryption tasks, to the `singleThreadedExecutor` services.

There are actually more complex locking mechanics that would allow you to use the same blocking queue for all tasks, while still keeping single-task-per-free-engine execution strategy. The advanced section of Java Concurrency in Practice, which is a great book to have a look at, can give you some directions about such.

Comment: I second Java Concurrency in Practice, see cout down latch.